# How can be normalized value from logistic function used to determine probability of binary classifier outcome?

Tags: neural-networks, binary-data, normalization

I would like to discuss chapter that comes from [Foreign-Exchange-Rate Forecasting With Artificial Neural Networks](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-71720-3).

This chapter (see screenshot) describes a binary classifier made from neural network output values (this case predicts binary output). I understand meaning of these formulas but what I do not understand is equation 12.4 in the sense how can be normalized value $g_i^+(x)$ used as a probability value for positive outcome and $1 - g_i^-(x)$ for negative outcome prediction?

Q: How is strong connection between predicted value from neural network and probability of predicted binary outcome?

**Edit1:** @mhdadk: I am aware of this work with probability in binary output, my question was more about how relevant is the normalization with the sigmoid logical function itself to produce confidence / probability measure (probability density).

I'm thinking that, for example, if the input to normalization function is in the interval approx. $(-\infty, -5)$ or $(5,+\infty)$ will basically still be normalized to the value of 1 (simply and figuratively speaking). With respect to sigmoid function everything except values from the interval $(-5,5)$ will be "truncated" to the value very near of 1. And outside the interval $(-5,5)$ there is infinitely more values than inside this interval.

How does the probability, after conversion to the normalized value $(0,1)$, is significant in this manner?

[image]

Comment: I think you are asking about the "squishing" behavior of the sigmoid function for extreme values, those beyond, say, -5 and 5. If so, what exactly do you want to know about these extreme values? By the way, [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.54.27) may offer the insight you are looking for.

Comment: You appear to be trying to do something that would be quite simple with a statistical regression model.   And "binary classifier outcome" doesn't mean very much.  Remember that classifiers are forced choice dichotomizers which is seldom what is really needed to solve a problem.   See for example [this](https://fharrell.com/post/classification).

Answer (score 0):

Given two classes $c_1$ and $c_2$, if
$$
p(c_1 \mid x) = g_i^+(x)
$$
and [since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Second_axiom)
$$
p(c_1 \mid x) + p(c_2 \mid x) = 1
$$
then
\begin{align}
p(c_1 \mid x) + p(c_2 \mid x) &= 1 \\
p(c_2 \mid x) &= 1 - p(c_1 \mid x) \\
p(c_2 \mid x) &= 1 - g_i^+(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added clarification to my question.